# Why query is taking time when I select one column before *?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why is this query taking time? It took more than 3 minutes, then I had to cancel the query execution.

```
SELECT TOP 1 EventNAme, * 
FROM DDLAudit WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

But this query is returning results in one second.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM DDLAudit WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

As far as I know, ordering the columns in the select query doesn't affect performance.

Comment: The ordering of the columns doesn't, but the ordering of the rows **does**. Due to your use of ordinal position for the `ORDER BY` (something many people suggest against), then your queries are quite different.

Comment: @Larnu But this much? Its taking more than 3 mins?

Comment: If your table `DDLAudit` has an index on the first column (we have no idea what that column is), then ordering the data is trivial for the data engine; especially if that index is the `CLUSTERED INDEX`. Take the above as a lesson learnt in being specific on what columns you want, and what column you want to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Larnu First column is Primary Key

Comment: Then it at least has an index to order by on; presumably, it has no such luxury with `EventName`.

Comment: @Larnu didn't get you,  so how can I solve this problem? Just FYI I added this EventName column recently

Comment: Tip: A look at the _actual execution plan_ would be enlightening. That's often the place to start with performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, the queries are actually quite different, because of your `ORDER BY` and the use of using ordinal positions ([Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)).

As such, your 2 queries should really be written like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
       EventName,
       * --This should also be all your columns in the table, including EventName again(?)
FROM dbo.DDLAudit --WITH (NOLOCK) --Do you have a "good" reason for using NOLOCK?
WHERE  EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY EventName DESC;

SELECT TOP (1)
       * --This should also be all your columns in the table
FROM dbo.DDLAudit --WITH (NOLOCK) --Do you have a "good" reason for using NOLOCK?
WHERE  EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY {What Ever the first column in the table dbo.DDLAudit is} DESC;
```

Ordering *can* be an expensive operation. This is *especially* so if the data engine has no indexes to help it order the data. You state in the comments that the first column in your table `DDLAudit` is the `PRIMARY KEY`. You don't state it this is a `CLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY` but if it is, then the RDBMS has the ideal index to sort your data by. If isn't your `CLUSTERED INDEX` then even still, SQL Server has something it can use to sort the data, likely with a key lookup.

If we assume that the PK is `CLUSTERED`, then the data engine's task is simply backward scan that index until it finds a row where `EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'` and then it can "short circuit" the query; stopping there.

For your other column, `EventName`, I suspect you don't have an index to help the RDBMS. As a result it needs to find *every single row* that fits the where `EventType = 'ALTER_PROCEDURE'`, then sort *all* that data on `EventName` in descending order, and finally return the first row.

If you want the first query to be faster, you'll need to ensure that it is adequately indexed (perhaps on `EventName` and `EventType`) and `INCLUDE` *all* the other columns from your table in the query. Though I would also suggest rewriting the query to not use `*` and actually *define* the columns you want. You don't need `EventName` returned twice in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of one fact. `ORDER BY 1` considers the first column of the SELECT query not the first column of the table itself. I just changed from `Order By 1` to `OrderBy FirstColumnOfTable`. and then it works as expected.

Comment: What would you have expected to therefore occur on a query like `SELECT * FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id ORDER BY 1;` then @viveknuna ? There are *two* tables, so how can it order by the first column in the table? `ORDER BY [int]` means order by the column in that ordinial position in the `SELECT`. So `SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases ORDER BY 2;` would error, is only 1 column in the `SELECT`. Bt, as I note in the answer, just *don't* use `ORDER BY {Ordinal}`; it's a bad habit.

Comment: Sure, Thank you for this lesson :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild guess here: You select the topmost column ordered by a specific field. If that field is indexed, that is easy. If it is not, it is a full table scan. `EventName` is probably not indexed, while when you select all fields, the first field is most likely your primary key, that obviously *is* indexed.

So if my guess is right, the difference comes from having to order by `EventName` instead of your primary key.

Comment: Order By is on the Primary key and I am doing Order By on PK only

Comment: Is `EventName` your PK? Because your post says you do `ORDER BY 1 DESC`.